# How to get only the dates where the last day of the month comes on Monday between two given dates

Tags: javascript, date

The return value should be a string like "10/31/2016 8/31/2017". This function returns all Mondays of the year, but I just need the dates with the last Mondays of every month if they are the last day of the month.

```
function getMondays(startYear, endYear) {
  const startDate = new Date(startYear, 0, 2)
  const endDate = new Date(endYear, 11, 32)

  var i = startDate,
  month = i.getYear(),
  mondaysOfYear = []

  while (i.getDay() !== 2) {
  i.setDate(i.getDate() + 1)
  }

  while (i.getYear() === month) {
    mondaysOfYear.push(new Date(i.getTime()))
    i.setDate(i.getDate() + 7)
  }
  return mondaysOfYear
}
getMondays(2017, 2017)
```

Comment: Iterate over months in the range, set date to 1st day of every month, go back one day `date.setDate( date.getDate() - 1);` and check if `date.getDay() === 2`

Comment: how do you get 10/31/2016 if startYear is 2017

Comment: Why `endDate = new Date(endYear, 11, 32)`? That will be 1 January the following year.

Comment: FYI, the terribly troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 and later. See [*Tutorial* by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Comment: Your example dates of "10/31/2016 8/31/2017" are incorrect. The cases in 2016 & 2017 where the end of month is a Monday are: 2016-02-29, 2016-10-31, 2017-07-31. See online calendar [for 2016](https://www.timeanddate.com/calendar/?year=2016&country=1) and [for 2017](https://www.timeanddate.com/calendar/?year=2017&country=1).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your logic doesn't seem suitable. There is:

```
month = i.getYear(),
```

*getYear* returns a 2 digit year, assigning it to a variable called "month" does not seem sensible. Then:

```
while (i.getDay() !== 2) {
  i.setDate(i.getDate() + 1)
}
```

Will increment the date until getDay returns 2, which is Tuesday. Then:

```
if (i.getMonth() != prevMonth) mondaysOfYear.push(prevDate);
```

does not make any sense to me. I guess your algorithm is to set the date to Monday, then add weeks and if it ends up on the end of a month, save it. But you've not implemented it that way.

A simpler and potentially faster algorithm is to get the last day of each month from the start to the end and if it's a Monday, push it to an array. There are many ways to do that, here is one.

```js
function getMondays(startYear, endYear) {
  // Set start to 1 Jan of start year
  var start = new Date(startYear, 0);
  // Set end to 31 Dec of end year
  var end = new Date(endYear, 11,31);
  var mondays = [];
  
  do {
    // setDate to end of month 
    start.setMonth(start.getMonth() + 1, 0);

    // If it's a Monday, store it in US mm/dd/yyyy format
    if (start.getDay() == 1) {
      mondays.push(start.toLocaleString('en-us', {
        year:  'numeric',
        month: '2-digit',
        day:   '2-digit'
      }));
    }

    // Set date to start of next month
    start.setDate(start.getDate() + 1);
  } while (start <= end) 
 
  return mondays;
}

console.log( getMondays(2016,2017) );
```

Comment: FYI, the terribly troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 and later. See [*Tutorial* by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 1):

```js
function getMondays(startYear, endYear) {
  mondaysOfYear = []
  for (var y = startYear; y <= endYear; y++)
    for (var m = 1; m < 13; m++) {
      var d = new Date(y, m, 0);   // console.log(d.toDateString()) // "Mon Jul 31 2017"
      if (d.getDay() === 1) 
        mondaysOfYear.push(d.toLocaleDateString())
    }
  return mondaysOfYear
}

console.log(getMondays(2016, 2017).join(" "))        // "2/29/2016 10/31/2016 7/31/2017"
```

Answer (score 0):

This will fetch you all the last mondays -

```
function getMondays(startYear, endYear) {
  const startDate = new Date(startYear, 0, 2)
  const endDate = new Date(endYear, 11, 32)

  var i = startDate,
  month = i.getYear(),
  mondaysOfYear = []

  while (i.getDay() !== 2) {
  i.setDate(i.getDate() + 1)
  }
  var prevMonth = 0;
  var prevDate;
  while (i.getYear() === month) {
    if(i.getMonth()!= prevMonth) mondaysOfYear.push(prevDate);
    prevMonth = i.getMonth(); //Retaining the last month to compare
    prevDate = new Date(i.getTime()); //Retaining the last monday
    i.setDate(i.getDate() + 7); 
  } 
  mondaysOfYear.push(prevDate);//for December
  return mondaysOfYear
}
getMondays(2017, 2017);
```

Filtering out the dates when the month changes. Adding the last monday of December at last after the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

-- Edit

Here is a link to [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dgdumf2a/) in case it gave incorrect result here on  stackoverflow :)

```js
function getMondays(startYear, endYear) {
  var months = [31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31];
  var mondays = [];
  while(startYear <= endYear) {
    for(var i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
      var leapYear = startYear % 4 === 0 && i === 1;
      var currentDate = new Date(startYear, i, leapYear ? months[i]+1 : months[i]);
      if(currentDate.getDay() === 1)
        mondays.push(currentDate);
    }
    startYear += 1;
  }
  return mondays;
}

var mondays = getMondays(2016, 2017)
console.log(mondays)
```

Answer (score -1):

Your Question is not clear, but apparently you want to find all occurrences where the last day of the month happens to be a Monday.

## *java.time*

The modern approach uses the *java.time* classes. Specifically, the [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) class represents a date-only value without time-of-day and without time zone. Also the classes [`Year`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Year.html) and [`YearMonth`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/YearMonth.html) and [`DayOfWeek`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/DayOfWeek.html), as their name suggests.

Rather than pass mere integers, you can pass `Year` objects for type-safety, making your code more self-documenting.

```
Year startYear = Year.of( 2016 );
Year stopYear = Year.of( 2018 );
```

Define your utility method.

```
public List< LocalDate > calcMondays ( Year startYear , Year stopYear ) { … }
```

Pass that pair of objects.

```
List< LocalDate> dates = this.calcMondays( startYear , stopYear ) ;
```

I suggest consistent use of the Half-Open approach to defining a span-of-time. In this approach, the beginning is *inclusive* while the ending is *exclusive*. So a period of 2017-2019 would start on the first day of 2017 and run up to, but not include, the first day of 2019, for a period of 2 years.

Get the [`YearMonth`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/YearMonth.html) of the start and stop, representing the month as a whole.

```
YearMonth startYm = YearMonth.from( startYear.atDay( 1 ) ) ;
YearMonth stopYm = YearMonth.from( stopYear.atDay( 1 ) ) ;
```

Define a collection of our found dates.

```
int initialCapacity = ( int ) ChronoUnit.MONTHS.between( startYear.atDay( 1 ) , stopYear.atDay( 1 ) );
List< LocalDate > lastMondays = new ArrayList<>( initialCapacity ) ;
```

Define the day-of-week we are targeting. Use `DayOfWeek` enum.

```
DayOfWeek dow = DayOfWeek.MONDAY ;
```

Define a `TemporalAdjuster`, using an implementation found in `TemporalAdjusters` class.

```
TemporalAdjuster ta = TemporalAdjusters.lastInMonth( dow ) ;
```

Loop the months. For each, determine the first Monday. Use a [`TemporalAdjuster`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/temporal/TemporalAdjuster.html) implementation found in the [`TemporalAdjusters`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/temporal/TemporalAdjusters.html) class.

```
YearMonth ym = startYm ;
while( ym.isBefore( stopYm ) ) {
    LocalDate firstOfMonth = ym.atDay( 1 ) ;
    LocalDate ld = firstOfMonth.with( ta ) ;
    lastMondays.add( ld ) ;  // Collect our last-monday-of-this-month. 
    // Set up the next loop.
    ym = ym.plusMonths( 1 ) ;
}
```

Report.

```
System.out.println( lastMondays ) ;
```

See that [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/OFRUwi).

> [2016-01-25, 2016-02-29, 2016-03-28, 2016-04-25, 2016-05-30, 2016-06-27, 2016-07-25, 2016-08-29, 2016-09-26, 2016-10-31, 2016-11-28, 2016-12-26, 2017-01-30, 2017-02-27, 2017-03-27, 2017-04-24, 2017-05-29, 2017-06-26, 2017-07-31, 2017-08-28, 2017-09-25, 2017-10-30, 2017-11-27, 2017-12-25]

Now let's modify that loop to focus on cases only where the last day of the month happens to be a Monday.

```
YearMonth ym = startYm;
while ( ym.isBefore( stopYm ) ) {
    LocalDate endOfMonth = ym.atEndOfMonth();
    if ( endOfMonth.getDayOfWeek().equals( dow ) ) {
        lastMondays.add( endOfMonth );  // Collect our last-monday-of-this-month.
    }
    // Set up the next loop.
    ym = ym.plusMonths( 1 );
}
```

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/FqLWgK).

> [2016-02-29, 2016-10-31, 2017-07-31]

Notice that these results differ from those given in the Question. I verified that these here are correct, and the Question’s results are incorrect.

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).